# How can I remove characters that appear consecutively more than two times from a string?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    
    int size;
    size = str.length();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){                      
        for(int j=i+2;j<size;j++){
            if(str[i]==str[j])                  //detect str[i]>2
                cout<<str[i]<<endl;             //print str[i]>2
            else
                cout<<"no occurrences"<<endl;}
 }
}
```

This is the code I'm starting with. My idea behind it would be looping the string until a letter appears more than two times consecutively and if it does, remove every other occurrence, so only two remain.

edit: added a nested for that detectes and prints str[i]>2

Comment: By more than 2 times , do you mean consecutively or in whole string ?

Comment: @anirudh consecutively

Comment: @JeremyFriesner fixed :)

Comment: Your idea doesn't sound that bad. Try to implement it. If you get stuck [edit] your question and show your attempt.

Comment: @Scheff i found a solution for the nested loop :)  i can't understand the using of str.erase() to delete those occurrences though 

Comment: What's your problem with [std::string::erase()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)? The first parameter is the index, the 2nd the number of characters to delete. So, it should be something like `str.erase(i, 1);`. However, please, don't forget that this will reduce the size of string by one. You should decrement the `size` when you erase a character.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of erasing characters (i.e. do the modification in place), you could also consider to write the result to a new string. So, you had to copy only those characters which are not repeated more than twice.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle a bit to send my answer – and taking OP the joy to find the solution on his own.

However, my solution doesn't use `std::string::erase()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  // get input
  std::string str;
  //std::cin >> str; // doesn't read white space
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  std::cout << str << std::endl; // show input
  // check whether enough input is available
  size_t size = str.length();
  if (size < 3) return 0; // nothing to do
  // remove all occurrences of more than two equal consecutive characters
  char c0 = str[0], c1 = str[1]; // 1st and 2nd character
  size_t iW = 2; // write index
  for (size_t iR = 2; iR < size; ++iR) {
    char c2 = str[iR];
    if (c0 != c1 || c1 != c2) {
      str[iW++] = c2; // write character to keep
      c0 = c1; c1 = c2; // shift characters
    }
  }
  str.resize(iW); // clip string to new length
  // done
  std::cout << str << std::endl; // show output
}
```

Output:

```
Hellllo World
Hello World
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbc3acc1afa96453)

Erasing something in the middle of a container with consecutive storage like `std::string` (or `std::vector`) is a not really cheap operation. Doing this repeatedly (in case) makes it worse.

The reason is that erasing something in the middle means effectively to shift all following elements up. Hence this can end up in quadratic complexity (O(n²)) due to the two nested loops.

With the solution, I use instead everything is done in one loop – linear complexity (O(n)) – better.

Actually, I once came to this solution in productive work where the input data was that large that the quadratic complexity was unacceptable for us (strictly speaking, for our customers) as taking much too long time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you version, this is also mine, which as you said is less efficient

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(){
string str;
    cin>>str;
    
int size;
size=str.length();

 for(int i=0;   i<size; i++){                      
//detect str[i]>2
       for(int j=i+2;  j<size; j++){
            if(str[i]==str[j])                          
//deletes at position
                str.erase(i, 1);}
}                      

    cout<<"new string is: "<<str<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

as you also said, size does not change after erase, how do i update that?

also with specific phrases i get this error

```
eeeerzrrrttsjjjs
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 13) > this->size() (which is 12)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Either use `for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)` (and in the inner loop as well, and drop variable `size`) or just add a `--size;` where you erase. (Don't forget the `{ }` in this case.)

Comment: A side note: `std::string::length()` returns a `size_t` which has the appropriate platform dependent size but is always an unsigned integral. Hence, `int` is an unlucky choice for `size`, `i`, and `j`. (With the appropriate warning level, your compiler would tell you this.) I recommend just to use `size_t` instead.

Comment: Btw. the error results precisely from the fact that `size` gets outdated once you erased something. Hence, your loop runs too long and finally does an out-of-bound access to the string `str`. You have managed to chose a proper sample input to prove this. ;-)

Comment: thanks @Scheff everything works well and i learnt new things. have a nice day :)